# Reactjs: useState state value is empty when updating it inside another function with onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function `handleTagSearch()` assigned to `onChange`. Inside this function I put the `event.target.value` to a state `tag` and then make an `axios` call with the `tag` state. But, the issue I noticed is, on the very first state change, this `tag` state is not updating instead it's value empty.

```
const [ tag, setTag ] = useState('');
const [ tags, setTags ] = useState([]);

const handleTagSearch = async(val) => {
    console.log("target val: ", val);
    setTag(val);
    console.log("value of tag: ", tag);
    const url = '127.0.0.1:8000/api/tag?name=' + tag;
    const resp = await axios.get(url);
    ...
};

return (
    <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            name="tags"
            value={tag}
            onChange={e=>handleTagSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
    </div>
);
```

How do I update the `tag` state properly with every input?

Comment: setTag is asynchronous it will not update instantly. use the `val`  variable instead.

Comment: also missing `http://` from your url

Comment: but I need the `tag` value later to update the `tags` array state

Comment: take a look at `useEffect` you can check if tag is empty or not. `if (tag) // do something`

Answer (score 1):

You should get your value seperately and then make your request inside of a useEffect.

```
const [ tag, setTag ] = useState('');
const [ tags, setTags ] = useState([]);


// API call here 

useEffect(() =>  {
const handleTagSearch = async(val) => {
  
    console.log("value of tag: ", tag);
    const url = '127.0.0.1:8000/api/tag?name=' + tag;
    const resp = await axios.get(url);
    ...
};
 if(tag) ( handleTagSearch(val));

}, [tag])



return (
    <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            name="tags"
            value={tag}
            onChange={e=> setTag(e.target.value)} // set the value like this
        />
    </div>
);
```

This way you'll get your tag state in time.

**Edit:** You can also directly call the function with `e.target.value` if you don't want to store it.

Comment: But won't this `useEffect` run before anything else renders?

Comment: @forest you're correct, first he can do if check, let me update

Answer (score 1):

You are able to doing it instead:

```js
const [ tag, setTag ] = useState('');
const [ tags, setTags ] = useState([]);

const handleTagSearch = (event) => {
    const { target : { value } } = event;
    return setTag(value);
};

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (tag.length){
       (async ()=> {
          console.log(
            "value of tag: ", tag
          );
          const url = '127.0.0.1:8000/api/tag?name=' + tag;
          const resp = await axios.get(url);
          //...
       })();
    };
} , [tag]);

return (
    <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            name="tags"
            value={tag}
            onChange={handleTagSearch}
        />
    </div>
);
```